# Проблема с обновлением модели QAbstractTableModel в QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qtreeview, qabstracttablemodel

У меня есть модель, содержащая список класса `MyClass`. Для обновления данных в модели я написал функцию `updateData`, которая передаёт в модель новый список класса `MyClass`.

Класс `MyClass` содержит параметр (атрибут `parameter`), от которого зависят значения некоторых столбцов модели. После обновления данных модели в функции `updateData` запускается поток `MyThread`, в котором происходит заполнение параметра (выполняется функция `setParameter`) каждого элемента списка `MyClass` модели. Мне нужно, чтобы при изменении значения параметра, все связанные с ним ячейки таблицы обновлялись.

Я попробовал решить это следующим образом: я добавил в класс `MyClass` сигнал `setParameter_signal`, который испускается функцией `setParameter`. 
Сигналы элементов списка я подключаю в функции `updateData`. Мне удалось добиться желаемого обновления ячеек таблицы, но по какой-то причине программа иногда крашится:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

при обновлении данных модели.

Ниже приведён минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку, которую я пытаюсь исправить, необходимо много раз нажать кнопку "Update" (не дожидаясь завершения потока `MyThread`). Помогите найти и исправить ошибку.

```
import typing
from random import randint
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread, QModelIndex, Qt, QPersistentModelIndex


class MyClass(QObject):
    setParameter_signal: pyqtSignal = pyqtSignal()  # The signal emitted when the parameter is changed.

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QObject.
        self.parameter = None

    def setParameter(self, value):
        self.parameter = value
        self.setParameter_signal.emit()  # Emit a signal that the parameter has been changed.


class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, thread_data_list: list[MyClass]):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QThread.
        self._thread_data_list: list[MyClass] = thread_data_list

    def run(self) -> None:
        for i, my_class_instance in enumerate(self._thread_data_list):
            if self.isInterruptionRequested(): break
            self.usleep(100)
            my_class_instance.setParameter(i)


class Column:
    def __init__(self, header: str | None = None, display_function=None, parameter_dependence: bool = False):
        self.header: str | None = header
        self.getDisplay = display_function
        self.parameter_dependence: bool = parameter_dependence

    def __call__(self, role, *data):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return None if self.getDisplay is None else self.getDisplay(*data)


class MyModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QAbstractTableModel.
        self._data_list: list[MyClass] = []
        self._thread: MyThread | None = None
        self.columns: tuple[Column, Column] = (
            Column(header='First',
                   display_function=lambda my_class_instance: 'Name'),
            Column(header='Second',
                   display_function=lambda my_class_instance: '' if my_class_instance.parameter is None else my_class_instance.parameter,
                   parameter_dependence=True),
        )

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self._data_list)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return len(self.columns)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> typing.Any:
        column: Column = self.columns[index.column()]
        my_class_instance: MyClass = self._data_list[index.row()]
        return column(role, my_class_instance)

    def updateData(self, data_list: list[MyClass]):
        """Sets the model data."""
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._stopThread()
        self._data_list = data_list
        '---------Connecting setParameter_signal signals to slots---------'
        def emitDataChanged(persistent_index: QPersistentModelIndex):
            index: QModelIndex = QModelIndex(persistent_index)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        for row, my_class_instance in enumerate(self._data_list):
            for column, my_column_instance in enumerate(self.columns):
                if my_column_instance.parameter_dependence:  # Only for columns that depend on the parameter.
                    index: QModelIndex = self.index(row, column)
                    persistent_index: QPersistentModelIndex = QPersistentModelIndex(index)
                    my_class_instance.setParameter_signal.connect(lambda: emitDataChanged(persistent_index))  # Connect the update slot.
        '-----------------------------------------------------------------'
        self.endResetModel()
        self._startThread(self._data_list)

    def _startThread(self, data_list: list[MyClass]):
        self._thread = MyThread(data_list)
        self._thread.start()

    def _stopThread(self):
        if self._thread is not None:
            self._thread.requestInterruption()
            self._thread.wait()
            self._thread = None


class Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # __init__() QMainWindow.
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.main_verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setModel(MyModel())
        self.main_verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('Update')
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.tableView.model().updateData([MyClass() for _ in range(randint(1500, 3000))]))
        self.main_verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Form()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Версия PyQt6 какая?

Comment: Как минимум с PyQt5 под Линуксом проблема не воспроизводится. С запуском через PyQt6 у меня не вышло - какие то проблемы при установке пакета.

Comment: Протестировал с `PyQt5`, `PyQt6`, `PySide2`, `PySide6`. Проблемы воспроизвести так и не удалось.

Comment: @MaximTimakov, PyQt6 6.5.0. Заметил, что если изменить в функции `updateData` строчку `my_class_instance.setParameter_signal.connect(lambda: emitDataChanged(persistent_index))  # Connect the update slot.` на `my_class_instance.setParameter_signal.connect(lambda pi=persistent_index: emitDataChanged(persistent_index))  # Connect the update slot.`, то ошибка изменится на `RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type MyClass has been deleted` (в строчке `self.setParameter_signal.emit()  # Emit a signal that the parameter has been changed.`).

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю вашу логику с классами и
какую тяжелую задачу вы собираетесь выполнять в дополнительном потоке.

Вы пишите, что после каких-то событий надо обновить все ячееки таблицы,
т.е. установить новую модель.

Пусть этим событием будет клик по кнопке 'Update'.
Попробуйте мой вариант обновления.

---

Обратите внимание, что:

- `randint(3_000, 10_000)`, чтобы было веселее;
- вставил расчета прошедшего времени, чтобы вам было понятно
  сколько времени затрачивается (`в миллисекундах`) на выполнение
  некоторых фрагментов кода.

---

```
import typing
from random import randint
'''
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QObject, pyqtSignal, \
    QThread, QModelIndex, Qt, QPersistentModelIndex
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Column:
#    def __init__(self, header: str | None = None, display_function=None, parameter_dependence: bool = False):
    def __init__(self, header=None, display_function=None, parameter_dependence=False):
        self.header = header
        self.getDisplay = display_function
        self.parameter_dependence: bool = parameter_dependence

    def __call__(self, role, *data):
        print(f'def __call__(self, role, *data): {data}') #
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return None if self.getDisplay is None else self.getDisplay(*data)
            

class MyClass(QObject):                                   # ??? ?
    # ??? ?
    # Сигнал, излучаемый при изменении параметра.
    setParameter_signal: pyqtSignal = pyqtSignal()  

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                             
        self.parameter = None

    def setParameter(self, value):
        self.parameter = value
        # Сигнал, излучаемый при изменении параметра.
        self.setParameter_signal.emit()  


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._data = data
        
    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data)
        
    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data[0]) if self.rowCount() else 0
        
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
                column = index.column()
                if 0 <= column < self.columnCount():
                    return self._data[row][column]


class Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.main_verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
#        self.tableView.setModel(MyModel())
        self.main_verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('Update')
        self.button.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.populateTable('custom')                           # +++
#            lambda: self.tableView.model().updateData(
# ?                [MyClass() for _ in range(randint(1500, 3000))]  
#            )
        )
        self.main_verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button)

        self._data = []                                                    # !!! +++
        
    def populateTable(self, mode):                                         # +++
        # Класс QElapsedTimer обеспечивает быстрый способ расчета прошедшего времени.
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qelapsedtimer.html#elapsed
        timer = QElapsedTimer() 
        timer.start() 

        model = self.tableView.model()
        if model is not None:   
            self.tableView.setModel(None)
            model.deleteLater()

        self.value = randint(3_000, 10_000)                                  # !!!       
        if len(self._data) != self.value:             
            del self._data[:]
            rows = list(range(self.value))

            self.columns: tuple[Column, Column] = (
                Column(header='First',
                       display_function=lambda my_class_instance: 'Name'),
                Column(header='Second',
                       display_function=lambda my_class_instance: '' if my_class_instance.parameter is None else my_class_instance.parameter,
                       parameter_dependence=True),
            )
# +++
            for row in rows:
                # ? MyClass()
                parameter = row
                columns: tuple[Column, Column] = (
                    Column(header='First',
                           display_function='Name'),
                    Column(header='Second',
                           display_function='' if parameter is None else parameter,
                           parameter_dependence=True),
                )
  
                items = []
                for col, column in enumerate(columns):
                    if col == 0:
                        items.append(columns[0].getDisplay)
                    if col == 1: 
                        items.append(columns[1].getDisplay)
                self._data.append(items)

        print(f'111 {mode}: {timer.elapsed():>4} milliseconds;  {self.value} строк')                 
        timer.start()          

        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(False)                           # !!!
        model = TableModel(self._data, self.tableView)                    # !!!
        self.tableView.setModel(model)                                    # !!!

        print(f'222 {mode}: {timer.elapsed():>4} milliseconds;  {self.value} строк\n')
                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Form()
    window.resize(250, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное, мне стоит подробнее описать свою проблему. Мне нужно обновлять ячейки второго столбца по мере получения данных (значений атрибута `parameter`). Получение данных происходит в дополнительном потоке, значения заранее не известны. Приведённый мной код является частью программы, воспроизводимым примером. Поэтому нельзя отказываться от `MyClass`, `MyThread` и т.д. Устанавливать новую модель тоже нежелательно. Для большего понимания проблемы можете посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77344753/22375658) эту же проблему в другой формулировке.